# Set a minimum price an NFT can be listed on exchanges for

Tags: solidity, erc-721, exchanges, opensea

Is it possible to have a minimum price for a ERC721 contract that would prevent the token being traded on exchanges if listed below that set price. (Not the mint price of the token itself)

Say an item was listed for less that 0.01 eth, would it be possible to detect this listing, and then block the transfer function?

Comment: Hi, @ablekane, please follow up, have an answer here

Answer (score 1):

Will you allow people to transfer things to themself?

Will you allow people to transfer on third-party exchanges?

If yes then you cannot control or see (on-chain) how those are proceeding.

---

Also, in general I think a product will be better if it does not depend on price appreciation.